# SQL sequential IF conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Tasks`. I want to sum the number of tasks status types (open, closed) and priorities grouped by project.

Something like this:

```
===============================================================================================
| Project   |   Closed  |   Major   |   Moderate    |   Minor   | Total 
===============================================================================================
|Project 1  |   4       |   3       |   0           |   0       | 7
|Project 2  |   1       |   0       |   2           |   5       | 8
|Project 3  |   10      |   8       |   3           |   4       | 25
```

The "priority" is determined by the ability to find a keyword within a VarChar field. (I know, very bad, but no problems there)

*The part I can't figure out* is how can I write the query so that IF I determine priority is "Major", break, or move on to the next task. Once I've determined the priority is "Major" the other priorities (Moderate, and Minor) should be ignored. The same goes for "Moderate". If I find "Moderate" I should not worry about Minor. **This is the part I'm having trouble with.** **How do I create an if statement based on results from another select?**

This is what I have so far which gives me all the counts...but the priorities are not "chained" or dependent on the match condition of the parent.

```
SELECT  Project, 
        count(status) as "Status Count"
        ,sum(case when status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) as Closed
        ,sum(case when status = 'Open' then 1 else 0 end) as "Open"
        ,sum(case when CHARINDEX ( 'Major', DefectSummary COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Major
        ,sum(case when CHARINDEX ( 'Moderate', DefectSummary COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Moderate
        ,sum(case when CHARINDEX ( 'Minor', DefectSummary COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Minor

FROM Tasks
GROUP BY Project
```

***DISCLAIMER***: I know this is a terrible data model. I inherited it from a previous developer. I'm in the process of overhauling the entire system but I need to be able to generate reports as it is now until I finish the new system.

Comment: I think `PIVOT` would accomplish this.  Basically taking the generated information from your query then pivoting them out.  Have you tried looking into that option?

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer I have not... looking into it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a subquery to determine the priority and then use that in your outer query:

```
SELECT  Project
        ,count(status) as "Status Count"
        ,sum(case when status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) as Closed
        ,sum(case when status = 'Open' then 1 else 0 end) as "Open"
        --
        ,sum(case when priority = 'Major' then 1 else 0 end) as Major
        ,sum(case when priority = 'Moderate' then 1 else 0 end) as Moderate
        ,sum(case when priority = 'Minor' then 1 else 0 end) as Minor
        ,sum(case when priority = 'Unknown' then 1 else 0 end) as Unknown
from
( select t.*
  ,      case
         when CHARINDEX ( 'Major', DefectSummary COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0
         then 'Major'
         when CHARINDEX ( 'Moderate', DefectSummary COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0
         then 'Moderate'
         when CHARINDEX ( 'Minor', DefectSummary COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0
         then 'Minor'
         else 'Unknown'
         end
         priority
  from   tasks t
) tasks
GROUP
BY    Project
```

Comment: Quick follow up question: You added an 'Unknown' field and I have since realized I'd like to take advantage of the 'Unknown' and display that field too. Do you know how I can display the sum of unknowns?

Comment: @capdragon: Just add it as additional field. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that and realized I was doing it wrong. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be preparing a data source with the results of substring searches, exposing that source as a *Common Table Expression* (CTE), and basing the `GROUP BY` on that source:

```
WITH Task_CTE (Project, Status, Closed, Open, Major, Moderate, Minor)
AS (
    SELECT
        Project, 
        status
    ,   case when status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end as Closed
    ,   case when status = 'Open' then 1 else 0 end as "Open"
    ,   case when CHARINDEX ( 'Major', DefectSummary COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as Major
    ,   case when CHARINDEX ( 'Moderate', DefectSummary COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as Moderate
    ,   case when CHARINDEX ( 'Minor', DefectSummary COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as Minor
    FROM Tasks
)
SELECT
    Project
,   count(status)
,   sum(Closed) as Closed
,   sum("Open") as "Open"
,   sum(Major) as Major
,   sum(CASE WHEN Major=1 THEN 0 ELSE Moderate END) as Moderate
,   sum(CASE WHEN Major=1 OR Moderate=1 THEN 0 ELSE Minor END) as Minor
FROM Task_CTE
GROUP BY Project
```

Using this approach lets your grouping `SELECT` see the flags prepared by the "raw" `SELECT` of the CTE. In the query above, the flags of `'Moderate'` and `'Minor'` are ignored when `'Major'` is present.

Answer (score 0):

In case you ever want to modify the priority list, you can separate it from the query logic:

```
DECLARE @DefectPriorities TABLE ([Priority] int, [DefectType] varchar(max))
INSERT @DefectPriorities VALUES
  (1,'Major'    ), 
  (2,'Moderate' ),
  (3,'Minor'    )

;WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT
    [Project]
   ,[DefectType]
   ,COUNT(CASE [Status] WHEN 'Closed' THEN 1 END) [Closed]
   ,COUNT(*) [Total]
  FROM tasks t2
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 [DefectType]
    FROM @Priorities
    WHERE CHARINDEX([DefectType],[DefectSummary] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0
    ORDER BY [Priority]
  ) t3
  GROUP BY [Project],[DefectType]
)
SELECT *
FROM t1
PIVOT(COUNT([DefectType]) FOR [DefectType] IN ('Major','Moderate','Minor') ) t4
```

Comment: I think OP was already in that process, but the suggestion is good though.